# Cisco ASA 5585-x Failover Virtual MAC address

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, failover

I have configured Cisco ASA 5585-x with Active/Standby mode, cisco best practice saying you should use `Virtual MAC` address on interface to avoid traffic disruption when you do failover. now question is what MAC address i should use so it won't conflict with any other device in datacenter can i use `aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa` , `bbbb.bbbb.bbbb.bbbb` OR can i use Burn-in MAC address of physical interface as virtual Mac so i don't need to worry about any kind of conflict (I didn't find in cisco guide saying you can use Read Burn-in MAC address as virtual so wanted to make sure what other people doing here?)

I have Port-channel configured on cisco ASA so do i need to configure Virtual MAC address on `port-channel` interface also or just VLAN interface like `PortChannel1.10` ?

Comment: Have you already seen the discussion about this at https://community.cisco.com/t5/network-security/asa-virtual-mac-best-practice/td-p/1446162 ?

Comment: I haven't but now i can see it, i got confused when i saw accepted answer is "You can't do it" but last post saying you can with `failover mac` command so look like i can use burn-in MAC address as a virtual MAC address :) but now question is how to deal with PortChannel interface because they have same MAC address for all VLANs